# What percentage of questions here that qualify for an automatic reopen review on closure due to popularity get reopened as a result?

Tags: support, review-queues, statistics, vote-to-reopen, popularity

One (apparently little-known) way that closed questions can be added to the reopen review queue, in addition to the usual methods of receiving a reopen vote or an edit with the review box checked, is [immediately upon closure if the question is "popular"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/377214) based on its score, the score of its top answer, or its view rate per month.

Here, I often see questions, especially older ones, that have gotten lots of views and votes (possibly over the years), that are eventually closed. Many of these were posted years ago and were either not a good fit in the first place or were later made off-topic due to scope changes: I was [just pointed to one example today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371621/377214). This leads me to believe that this automatic add may not be useful, if most questions added to the reopen queue via that route fall into that category and/or get left closed in review.

Before making a request in that regard, I'd like to know: what proportion of questions that get added to the queue via the "popularity" route eventually get reopened through the task it spawns? It'd be nice if someone with the appropriate privileges (mod or staff) could query for this.

Comment: Mods have no way of accessing this information beyond what a normal user could do. Is it available in SEDE?

Comment: @CodyGray if you know what triggers it, you could figure out which questions entered the queue due it. Look for questions that entered multiple times.

Comment: I don't like this system, since it becomes a "we put this question to review until we find 3 users that vote to reopen it". That makes sure that it gets reopened just because stars misaligned.

Comment: @Braiam best way to counter such brainless tricks would be for reviewers to vote down the question (and vote delete if they have enough rep). If there was a bot reporting such robo-reopens to SOCVR, company would probably eventually "decide" that they don't really want this auto-pushing

Comment: @gnat the thing is that I don't want vote buttons in any queue that isn't first post/late answers. We want reviewers to focus on one thing and one thing alone: whenever or not the question needs reopening.

Comment: @Braiam I meant voting outside of the queue (I too prefer absense of votes in review UI for the same reasons as you)